# How to check if a string contains certain characters and split it in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to check the existence of following characters in a given string:

```
characters =('N', 'E', 'M', 'H', 'T', 'V', 'L', 'C' )
string = 2449.555N06704.2855EM0701H071T44.098V11.764L0.372C1
```

And if string contains these characters, then need to split them into values as following to insert them in `details_Tb`:

```
N = 2449.7183 
E = 06704.2855 
T = 0701
H = 071
T = 44.098
V = 11.764
L = 0.372
C =  1
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: I fail to see the logic happening between your input and the expected output. Could you describe what you want to happen?

Comment: Your out put is totally confusing .. plz check is that you really want, if so what is the logic..

Comment: String contains information regarding a device current status i.e. N is north co.ordinate,E is East coardinate,V is voltage of device,T is temperature etc.I need to break the strng into chunks w.r.t chars after or before numeric values to save then in my detailsTb and represented N=2249.7183 to clearfy what i want to do with string just

Comment: @madivirgo_007 what happens if data is like N77.1234.88M5V ? What is wrong with my answer that provides the exact same output as your example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for this result

**result**:

```
N=2449.555
E=06704.2855
H=0701
T=071
V=44.098
L=11.764
C=0.372
```

then try this query..

```
DECLARE @CHARACTERS TABLE (CHARS CHAR(1)) 
INSERT INTO @CHARACTERS VALUES
('N'), ('E'), ('M'), ('H'), ('T'), ('V'), ('L'), ('C' );
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(500);
SET @STRING= '2449.555N06704.2855EM0701H071T44.098V11.764L0.372C1';

WITH CTE AS (
SELECT      CHARS+'='+CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(@STRING,
            CHARINDEX(CHARS,@STRING,1)-1)), PATINDEX('%[^0-9,.]%',
            REVERSE(LEFT(@STRING,CHARINDEX(CHARS,@STRING,1)-1)) + 'Z')-1))
            AS VARCHAR(50)) AS RESULT
FROM        @CHARACTERS )
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE LEN(RESULT)>2
```

**EDIT1 :**  As per the comment, if you want to insert the these values to detail_Tb table, please check the code below:

```
create table detail_Tb(N float,E float,M float,
            H float,T float,V float,L float,C float);

DECLARE @CHARACTERS TABLE (CHARS CHAR(1)) 
INSERT INTO @CHARACTERS VALUES
('N'), ('E'), ('M'), ('H'), ('T'), ('V'), ('L'), ('C' );
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(500);
SET @STRING= '2449.555N06704.2855EM0701H071T44.098V11.764L0.372C1';
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT      CHARS,CAST(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(@STRING,
            CHARINDEX(CHARS,@STRING,1)-1)), PATINDEX('%[^0-9,.]%',
            REVERSE(LEFT(@STRING,CHARINDEX(CHARS,@STRING,1)-1)) + 'Z')-1))
            AS VARCHAR(50)) AS RESULT
FROM        @CHARACTERS )
SELECT * into #tmp FROM CTE WHERE len(RESULT)>2  


select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(CHARS) 
                    from #tmp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'Insert into detail_Tb('+@cols+') 
              SELECT ' + @cols + ' from #tmp x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX([RESULT])
                for CHARS in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
execute(@query)     
Drop table #tmp
```

Comment: thanks for the repli and i chk the script it is the perfect solution  :)

Comment: How can I initialize each Value to a varible for insertion in my table ?

Comment: each value need to be save in respented column in detail_Tb ?

Comment: I need to merge this code to my trigger code,Can i use the code in triggers ?

Comment: @madivirgo_007: yes you can  use it with trigger

Comment: @madivirgo_007: if you want each value need to be save in respented column in detail_Tb, then check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for repling .I execute he code it show all data except M0701 is showing as Null

Comment: Sequence of values is not correct as code miss M values is 0701 and over.rite values after that.....

Comment: What is #temp, why u used it ?